# Substituting a calculated range into a lookup

Tags: excel

In the contents of cell `F3` I have the following formula (which takes one value on the current row and looks it up in another sheet, returning a range based upon where it was found):

`="'OBS Procedures'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),3) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),50)`

which outputs, as it ought, the text : `'OBS Procedures'!$C$1:$AX$1`

All good so far.

I have in another cell (which outputs the rightmost filled cell of the range generated by cell `F3`):

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT(F3)<>""),INDIRECT(F3))`

And this outputs , as it ought, the text : **5 : 18/07/2016**

Great.

But I'm wanting to get rid of cell `F3` entirely, and incorporate the formula for F3 into the second formula above.

Simply copying in the `F3` formula between the second `INDIRECT()` works fine. But copying it into the first F3 generates `#N/A`.

Specifically :

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("'OBS Procedures'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),3) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),50))<>""),INDIRECT(F3))`

generates `#N/A`

Whereas even

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("'OBS Procedures'!$C$1:$AX$1")<>""),INDIRECT(F3))`

and generates what I expect

(Keeping the intermediate cell or doing this in VBA, which is my usual go-to for anything more than simple formulae, isn't an option in this case)

I'm simply not seeing what I am doing wrong here - can anyone enlighten me, please?  :)

Comment: Maybe because you are referring to multiple cells in your indirect formula `$C$1:$AX$1`?

Comment: Go to `Formulas` >> `Evaluate Formula` and debug it.

Comment: Can I ask why you're first going to the effort to generate a text string which represents the range to be queried? This is almost never necessary, in my experience, and certainly not when it involves such convoluted use of  volatile functions such as INDIRECT.

Comment: Indirect() can take a range, and indeed using INDIRECT("'OBS Procedures'!$C$1:$AX$1") gives me the output that I expect also.  I've edited the above to make that clear.

Comment: Also, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)) is a circular and unnecessary construction. Assuming we take the example for row 1, for example, this is equivalent to simply A1. So you could equally write (for row 1): MATCH(A1,'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0).

Comment: Thanks XOR. I'm aware that it appears redundant, but I will eventually need to apply a row offset dependent on the value of the cell being looked up - so I did not want to simplify it at this stage.  This is pretty much why I'm using text strings - it just seemed a more flexible approach as I could build up each part of the string separately.

Comment: Actually you can achieve the same flexibility without the volatile INDIRECT and without the need to build a text string which represents an actual worksheet range.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in my comments, I'm afraid to say that the construction you are currently using is a very poor one indeed, and could be replaced with a set-up which is both non-volatile and far more efficient.

The reason for your error is due to the manner in which you are using the `ROW` function. In fact, for generating incremental integers in this manner, `ROW` is, for several reasons, inferior to `ROWS` (https://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/).

Despite its inferiority in this respect, however, this does not usually lead to errors. Here, you are a little unfortunate in that, due to the nature of your construction, Excel is expecting an array output from the portion:

`ROW()`

As such, and assuming for the sake of argument that the formula we are discussing is in row 1, this part:

`ADDRESS(ROW(),1)`

which, under different circumstances, would evaluate to:

`"$A$1"`

here evaluates instead to:

`{"$A$1"}`

since the `LOOKUP` is lending the necessary array-coercion to the overall construction such that the `ROW()` portion is expected to deliver an array output, albeit one containing just a single value. In fact, here (and you can see this by using the *Evaluate Formula* feature), this part evaluates to (for row 1), not `1`, but `{1}`.

And so here:

`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))`

is:

`INDIRECT({"$A$1"})`

and since, in general, `INDIRECT` is incapable of resolving an array of values (though this can be achieved via further manipulation), this part errors.

To avoid this, you can use `ROWS`, e.g. (for row 1):

`ADDRESS(ROWS($1:1),1)`

or else coerce the array output from `ROW` into a non-array type via some suitable additional function, e.g. `SUM`, viz:

`ADDRESS(SUM(ROW()),1)`

That said, I really think that you need to rethink your whole approach here. For example, this:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDEX('OBS Procedures'!$C:$AX,MATCH(A1,'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),)<>""),INDEX('OBS Procedures'!$C:$AX,MATCH(A1,'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),))`

assumed to be in row 1, would be equivalent to your:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("'OBS Procedures'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),3) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),'OBS Procedures'!A:A,0),50))<>""),INDIRECT(F3))`

(again assumed to be in row 1), and not only does not require the prior construction of a text string representing a range, but is also concise and, importantly, non-volatile.

Regards